# validate numeric with 1 special character

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want to validate numeric and allows the + (plus sign), but its not working

what i want

```
+63443 -> OK
8452 -> OK
s55sd -> Not OK
```

here's my code

```
var Nom = $("#addKonId1").val().split(" ").join("").replace(/^\s\s*/, '').replace(/\s\s*$/, '');

var intRegex = /^\d+$/;
if (!intRegex.test(Nom)) {
    alert("wrong Number");

} else {
    alert(Nom);
}
```

Comment: `/^[+]?\d+$/` maybe? Otherwise, what's not working?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson - Why do you need a bracket around `+`?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson - Yes I know, but my point is `\+` is clearly shorter than `[+]`.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 Matter of taste, they do the exact same thing, I just find it easier to quickly scan `/^[+]?[\d]+$/` and see which are characters vs. operators than `/^\+?\d+$/` is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regular expression for what you're looking for is:

```
^\+?\d+$
```

Which means "a string beginning with optionally one plus sign followed by one or more digits".

Your regex right now only tests for a string beginning with one or more digit characters. Alter `intRegex` like so:

```
var intRegex = /^\+?\d+$/;
```

On a side note, what you're doing in your first line with the replacing can simply be done with [`trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim):

```
var Nom = $("#addKonId1").val().split(" ").join("").trim();
```

Answer (score 2):

Try This

```
var Nom = $("#addKonId1").val().trim(" ");
var intRegex = /^\+?\d+$/;
            if(!intRegex.test(Nom)) {
                alert("wrong Number");

            }
            else{
                alert(Nom);
            }
```

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/p7LQG/2/)**